# Send specific signals to systemd for service shutdown

Tags: systemd

I have a remote server and connect via a browser to [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebooks hosted there. The jupyter service is run via `systemd`. The problem is that jupyter expects **two** `ctrl-c` commands within 5 seconds of each other to shut down cleanly. `systemd` sends only one signal to halt the process, then waits for a timeout, and when it sees that jupyter hasn't stopped, finally sends a kill signal. This leads to a long delay and an unclean exit when I want to stop or restart the service. I know that systemd has an `ExecStop` parameter but can't find any examples of how it is actually used, and how I can send the equivalent of two `ctrl-c` keystrokes via this mechanism.

My current service file is:

```
[Unit]
    Description=Jupyter notebook

[Service]
    Type=simple
    PIDFile=/var/run/jupyter-notebook.pid
    ExecStart=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser
    User=pgcudahy
    Group=pgcudahy
    WorkingDirectory=/home/pgcudahy
    Environment=PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python/libexec/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/cython/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/pgcudahy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

[Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So with some more research, what I want to send with `ctrl-c` is a `SIGINT` which can be done with `/bin/kill -s SIGINT`

Adding this to my service file shuts down jupyter cleanly

`ExecStop=/bin/kill -s SIGINT -$MAINPID & /bin/kill -s SIGINT -$MAINPID`

The whole file is

```
[Unit]
    Description=Jupyter notebook

[Service]
    Type=simple
    PIDFile=/var/run/jupyter-notebook.pid
    ExecStart=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser
    ExecStop=/bin/kill -s SIGINT -$MAINPID & /bin/kill -s SIGINT -$MAINPID
    User=pgcudahy
    Group=pgcudahy
    WorkingDirectory=/home/pgcudahy
    Environment=PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python/libexec/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/cython/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/pgcudahy/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

[Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This Q&A seems like a very roundabout way of going about things, considering that [the program supports the normal `SIGTERM` way of being told to terminate](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/8e7c99ad8d3fe59f98bb03e828307387a3694704/notebook/notebookapp.py#L1812).

Comment: How would you set up `systemd` to cleanly end the program without waiting for a timeout? Your comment comes off as condescending and is unhelpful.

Comment: Just use the normal mechanism as it stands, nothing special required, like [these people did back in 2016](https://gist.github.com/whophil/5a2eab328d2f8c16bb31c9ceaf23164f), like [this person did in 2018](https://gist.github.com/laeshiny/47f027a65a96db8ece004f87cad763da), and [like _the program itself_ does](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/8e7c99ad8d3fe59f98bb03e828307387a3694704/notebook/notebookapp.py#L488).  There's nothing in the handling of `SIGTERM` there that necessitates waiting for a timeout.

Comment: What is the reason to have two the same `/bin/kill` commands with `&`?

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked adding the following code to the "some_systemd.service" file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/DVR_Living_Room.sh
KillSignal=SIGINT
```

"SIGINT" is the kill signal interpreted as: "Ctrl + C" which does a clean exit.

I needed this signal for FFMPEG because any other type of exit during a live recording from FFMPEG will corrupt the video. FFMPEG only accepts "CTRL+C" as a valid exit to cleanly stop recording the video and not corrupt it.

Also, you can find a complete slew of different kill signals here:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: The question says ''how I can send the equivalent of two Ctrl-C keystrokes via this mechanism?''   I don't see an answer to that question.